# How to make the pattern, that will replace '^' symbol JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

I'm a newbie in JS, and I don't know how to make **pattern**, that would replace `^` symbol. Much thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The regex pattern would be :

```
pattern=/\^/g
```

Then you can use

```
text.replace(pattern, 'replace with')
```

as simple as that.